# Cannot find table 'noticia'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

I created this table called noticias

```
class CreateNoticia < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :noticias do |t|
      t.string :titulo
      t.date :data
      t.text :sumario
      t.text :texto
      t.boolean :destaque
      t.boolean :ativa

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and of course I created the model

```
class Noticia < ActiveRecord::Base
   #validations
end
```

and when I try to create a Noticia it throws:

cannot find table 'noticia' so far I've been creating the models with the `rails generate model` command and it has all worked out. But now this happens. I don't understand.

Does someone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

`noticia` seems to be plural form of `noticium`, so:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('noticia')
# => "noticia"
```

That's why Rails expect `noticia` table.

Comment: so what can i do? change the table name to noticium?

Comment: No, change model name to `Noticium` and table name to `noticia`. Model name should be in singular form, table name in plural.

Comment: i'll just rollback and redo everything. What name do you suggest for a table that represents news?

Comment: You can stay with table named `news` and model named `News`, but be aware of this:
http://gistflow.com/posts/116-plural-model-names-in-rails